# Getting another element through a method thats related to the current operation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Sorry for the bad title, simple couldn't figure out how to explain my problem.

Let's say i have 4 of these fields, and not just one. I want to increment or decrement each input field. Each input field has a "+" and "-" that does incremental and decremental tasks.

I have setup a method that register the v-on click even to a method. But how do i get what input field it was incremented on, cause 'this' would return the buttons of +/-

normally i would just use jquery with .parent().find('.input-number'); but i feel like this is dirty, and excessive for such a small thing. most be a better approach?

This is my markup

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="input-number-decrement" v-on:click="decrement()">–</span>
        <input class="input-number form-control" name="pack1" id="pack1" type="text" value="0" min="0">
        <span class="input-number-increment" v-on:click="increment()">+</span>            
      </div>
```

and looks like this
[example of the field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8zD0.png)

any help would great, since i'm stuck at this part :)

Comment: I assume you are looking for a Vue based answer? Is this part of a Vue component?

Answer (score 0):

I have created one `javascript` function for increment and decrement value by 1.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <span class="input-number-decrement" v-on:click="inc_dec('dec')">-</span>
    <input class="input-number form-control" name="pack1" id="pack1" type="text" value="0" min="0">
    <span class="input-number-increment" v-on:click="inc_dec('inc')">+</span>            
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function inc_dec(flag){
        var pack1 = document.getElementById('pack1');
        var inc_dec_by = 1;
        if(flag=='inc'){
            pack1.value = parseInt(pack1.value)+inc_dec_by;
        }
        if(flag=='dec'){
            pack1.value = parseInt(pack1.value)-inc_dec_by;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming above code is a vue component.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <span class="input-number-decrement" v-on:click="decrement()">–</span>
 <inputn v-model="value" class="input-number form-control" name="pack1" id="pack1" type="text" value="0" min="0">
 <span class="input-number-increment" v-on:click="increment()">+</span>            
</div>
```

In the script define a variable to hold the value.Then manipulate values using defined methods

```
<script>
export default{
 data: {
    value
  },
  methods: {
    decrement: function (event) {
    },
    increment: function (event) {
    }
  }
}
</script>
```